# file:write restarts Corona app

Tags: lua, corona-sdk

I am attempting to implement an auto-save feature into a mobile game.  I have the following code writing to the save file:

```
function saveFunc(input)
local saveData=input
local file = io.open( "saveFile.txt", "w" )

for i,val in ipairs(saveTable) do
    saveData=saveData.."\n"..val
end

file:write( saveData )
io.close( file )
end
```

This writes to the file correctly.  The problem is that after the function finishes, the whole app restarts.  Watching the output console, it re-prints the "Copyright (C)..." as if I had Relaunched the app.

I know it is this specific function because if I comment out the call for this function the game continues as normal.  I also tried commenting out the `io.close(file)` but the program still restarted.

How can I write to a file and not restart the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code used is saving the document to the local folder.  This means that every update of that file will re-launch the app (at least in the emulator).  To prevent this, save to `system.DocumentsDirectory` like so:

```
local file = io.open(system.pathForFile("pokedex.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory), "w" )
```